# Por que laravel incluye el contenido del HEAD en el BODY

Tags: laravel

Estoy haciendo una pagina en laravel pero a la hora de verla en el navegador muestra todo el contenido del head dentro del body y la etiqueta head la deja vacia. Estoy usando @yield y en la pagina que extiende uso @extends y @section no se si po ahi este el error ya estuve buscando pero no encuentro ninguna pregunta similar a la mia.

app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>@yield('title')</title>
    <!-- Fonts -->

    <!-- Styles -->
</head>

<body>
    @yield('menu')
    @yield('body')
<!--scripts-->
</body>

</html>
```

Y asi lo muestra en el navegador:

```
<html lang="en"><head></head><body><div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light row">

                <div class="col-md-4">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="http://localhost:8000/img/Letra-menu.png" alt="logo"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 d-flex justify-content-center"><img src="http://localhost:8000/img/Letra-menu-icono.png" alt="logoLang">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 d-flex justify-content-end">

                    <div class="dropdown">

                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="menu" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            Menu
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Inicio</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Notas de interes</a>
                                                        
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://localhost:8000/login">Entrar</a>
                                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="http://localhost:8000/register" hidden="">Registrar</a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>

        </nav></div>
    </div>
</div>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>    Detalles
</title>
    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:wght@400;600;700&amp;display=swap">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="/js/app.js" defer=""></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/2.5.4/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha512-7yA/d79yIhHPvcrSiB8S/7TyX0OxlccU8F/kuB8mHYjLlF1MInPbEohpoqfz0AILoq5hoD7lELZAYYHbyeEjag==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
```

Gracias amigos espero me puedan ayudar :)

Comment: Disculpa me refiero a la página que extiende de app, además dicho código va en tu pregunta

Comment: Gracias amigo ya agregue la la vista que extiende de app.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

Pagina que extiende de app.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title')
    RoosLanguages
@endsection

@include('menu.mainMenu')

@section('body')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                @include('asides.langaside')
            </div>
            <section class="col-md-8">
                <div>
                    <p>En RootsLanguages intentamos recopilar las funciones basicas de todos los lenguages de programacion. El objetivo es ayudarte a escojer un lenguaje que se te facilite y que conoscas la sintaxis basica para poder empezar un proyeco sencillo</p>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```